# Android: How do you use ListView to start an Activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I am writing my first Android application, and I have been struggling with this for over a week. It seems like the basis of all android applications yet I cannot understand how to do it. For example, if you are in the Android Settings Menu, you have a list and you click on "About", it takes you to the "About" Actvitiy etc.

I need my app to do that as well, I have 5 menu items that I want to be able to select and go to the Activity for the selected item.

Currently I have my items in a string_array, but I have nothing that corresponds the string name with the activity name I want to goto.

Can somebody please give me some tips? I am really struggling over here, kind of overwhelmed with the documentation. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how its done here in the [Settings](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=tree;h=refs/heads/froyo-release;hb=froyo-release) app.  They use a `PreferenceActivity` and embed the `Intent` in the XML file.

```
        <com.android.settings.IconPreferenceScreen
         android:title="@string/radio_controls_title"
         settings:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_wireless">
         <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
            android:targetPackage="com.android.settings"
            android:targetClass="com.android.settings.WirelessSettings" />
        </com.android.settings.IconPreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, but this app is based on preferencesActivity which is supposed to be used for your applications preferences, not really for your whole application lol

Answer (score 2):

You should start from reading the [Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

A particular section you should note is the [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) and [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

> Activating components: intents
>
> Content providers are activated when
>   they're targeted by a request from a
>   ContentResolver. The other three
>   components — activities, services, and
>   broadcast receivers — are activated by
>   asynchronous messages called intents.
>   An intent is an Intent object that
>   holds the content of the message. For
>   activities and services, it names the
>   action being requested and specifies
>   the URI of the data to act on, among
>   other things. For example, it might
>   convey a request for an activity to
>   present an image to the user or let
>   the user edit some text. For broadcast
>   receivers, the Intent object names the
>   action being announced. For example,
>   it might announce to interested
>   parties that the camera button has
>   been pressed.
>
> There are separate methods for
>   activating each type of component:
>
> - An activity is launched (or given something new to do) by passing an
>     Intent object to
>     Context.startActivity() or
>     Activity.startActivityForResult(). The
>     responding activity can look at the
>     initial intent that caused it to be
>     launched by calling its getIntent()
>     method. Android calls the activity's
>     onNewIntent() method to pass it any
>     subsequent intents.
>
>   One activity often starts the next one. If it expects a result back from
>     the activity it's starting, it calls
>     startActivityForResult() instead of
>     startActivity(). For example, if it
>     starts an activity that lets the user
>     pick a photo, it might expect to be
>     returned the chosen photo. The result
>     is returned in an Intent object that's
>     passed to the calling activity's
>     onActivityResult() method.
> - A service is started (or new instructions are given to an ongoing
>     service) by passing an Intent object
>     to Context.startService(). Android
>     calls the service's onStart() method
>     and passes it the Intent object.
>
>   Similarly, an intent can be passed to Context.bindService() to establish
>     an ongoing connection between the
>     calling component and a target
>     service. The service receives the
>     Intent object in an onBind() call. (If
>     the service is not already running,
>     bindService() can optionally start
>     it.) For example, an activity might
>     establish a connection with the music
>     playback service mentioned earlier so
>     that it can provide the user with the
>     means (a user interface) for
>     controlling the playback. The activity
>     would call bindService() to set up
>     that connection, and then call methods
>     defined by the service to affect the
>     playback.
>
>   A later section, Remote procedure calls, has more details about binding
>     to a service.
> - An application can initiate a broadcast by passing an Intent object
>     to methods like
>     Context.sendBroadcast(),
>     Context.sendOrderedBroadcast(), and
>     Context.sendStickyBroadcast() in any
>     of their variations. Android delivers
>     the intent to all interested broadcast
>     receivers by calling their onReceive()
>     methods.
>
> For more on intent messages, see the
>   separate article, Intents and Intent
>   Filters.